# How to create a loadable bundle on macOS?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

Looking to make a plug-in.

If I select 'Bundle' as the template when setting-up a macOS project in Xcode, this doesn't seem to create the actual content / structure required for a bundle.

Looking at Apple's docs it says...

```
// The directory layout of a typical loadable bundle. 
- MyLoadableBundle
    Contents/
        Info.plist
        MacOS/
            MyLoadableBundle
        Resources/
            Lizard.jpg
            MyLoadableBundle.icns
            English.lproj/
                MyLoadableBundle.nib
                InfoPlist.strings
            Japanese.lproj/
                MyLoadableBundle.nib
                InfoPlist.strings
```

How / where is this generated?

Have tried manually creating this structure but the result is not loadable. Surely there is a way of creating a loadable bundle directly from Xcode?

*** update ***

So, for a Bundle project called PluginTest with one file, plugin.swift, my understanding is that Xcode should have created something that looks like...

```
- PluginTest
      Contents/
          Info.plist
          MacOS/
          PluginTest
```

...where the root is a `.bundle`.

But, it looks like this...

```
- PluginTest
      PluginTest-Bridging-Header.h
      plugin.swift
      PluginTest.xcodeproj
```

...where the root is a normal directory folder.

I have tried manually generating the executable, manually creating the folder structure shown in the docs and adding the executable to the MacOS folder, and manually updating the principal class field in the Info  tab in Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

Just add your files to the project. It's probably best to create a group called Resources for the resources. Xcode will more or less take care of creating the structure of the target.

You can get more control by looking at the build phases, the "copy bundle resources" phase in particular.

The Info.plist file will be generated from the "Info" tab on for the target.

To expand on this. I just created a bundle project. This is what I see in Xcode:

[image: Xcode Bundle project structure]

From the top:

- `Resources` is a group I created and then added the pdf to, to make a resource
- `File.swift` is a file I added containing a Swift `struct` so that there would be some code in the bundle.
- `Products` is the product folder created by Xcode when I created the project and it contains the built bundle. NB this is a virtual view: the built bundle is actually located in a build directory somewhere under Xcode's derived data folder.
- `MyBundle-Bridging-Header.h` is a header file that was created when I added `File.swift`

When I added `ground rent.pdf` to the Resources group, the file open dialogue had some extra options in it that I ignored and just left as defaulted.

The built bundle has the following structure:

[image: Built bundle]

This I obtained by right clicking on the bundle in the Products folder in Xcode and selecting "Show in Finder" and then right clicking on the bundle in the Finder and selecting "show bundle contents". It has the proper structure as documented by Apple and I had to do nothing special in Xcode to make it like that.

A couple of things to note: the file Info.plist was generated automatically by the build. It reflects the values entered into the info tab for the MyBundle target.

[image: Info Tab]

The pdf is in the Resources folder because of the "copy bundle resources" build phase.

[image: Copy Bundle Resources]

Xcode figured out that the pdf was a resource and added that line automatically. That doesn't preclude me from adding other project files to the list. anything you do add there will be copied into the bundle's resource folder.

Comment: Thanks but not sure what I am doing wrong. Have provided an edit.

Comment: @chemFour You are confusing the structure of your project with the structure of the target. I'll add an update to my answer